# How to use sphinx_js with a "export default class"?

Tags: javascript, python, python-sphinx, jsdoc

I have a project with Python and Javascript code, which I would like to document using Sphinx. I fail to get [sphinx_js](https://github.com/mozilla/sphinx-js) working. My Sphinx project is in a docs subfolder. The Javascript code is in frontend/src, so in my `docs/conf.py` I configured:

```
js_source_path = "../frontend/src"
```

My JS code in `frontend/src/foo_controller.js` looks like this:

```
/**
 * Some JSDoc like documentation just for testing.
 */
export default class extends Controller {
    /**
     * More JSDoc documentation for a function.
     */
    connect() {...}
}
```

In my index.rst I have:

```
.. js:autoclass:: ???
      :members:
```

Whatever I tried for the `???` (foo_controller, controller/foo_controller, FooController, ...) I always get the error:

> No JSDoc documentation was found for object
> "..." or any
> path ending with that.

How to I have to replace the `???` to document my class?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but the `autodoc` logic for naming the object (your `???`) would be `package.module.class` in this case. The interesting thing (if I'm not mistaken) is that the `export default class` is nameless (you'd have to correct me on this). So by whatever name you reference a *"nameless class"* should be what you'd use in `???` maybe `default`, or `foo_controller.default`. A workaround would be giving it a name and trying by that name...(I'm speculating by comparison with python-sphinx)

Comment: `js_source_path` must be relative to your `conf.py`. In your project, you have configured this value such that `frontend` and `docs` are siblings in the same folder. Is that correct? Assuming it is correct, then try `.. js:autoclass:: Controller`. If that does not work, then perhaps the problem is the `export default` or `extends` within your class declaration?